# error on array retrieved from JOIN query on two tables

Tags: php, arrays, join

hope my title is clear. I am trying to retrieve results from two tables.
So I want everything (hence *) from the table called 'albums'.
and I want only all matching (with album_id) results from table 'contributors'.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM albums LEFT JOIN contributors ON albums.album_id = 
contributors.album_id ORDER BY albums.datum DESC; ") or die(mysql_error());

$aantal_rijen = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($aantal_rijen > 0) {

for ($i = 0; $i < $aantal_rijen; $i++){


$contributors[] = mysql_result($result, $i, 'contributors');}
```

but i get a list of similar errors:

> contributor not found in MySQL result index ...

Joining of two tables is totally new to my, and maybe it's not the way to go, but maybe it's just a plain simple error in this code, anyway, I'm stuck here,

all help is welcome
thx S

Comment: Which rows will be returned? Most likely you need to use something like `albums.contributor` - or use an alias in the query and select that

Comment: What's there in `$aantal_rijen`?

Comment: @kingkero, from table albums, each row is returned, but I skipped that part, since it works fine. From table contributors, only  row' contributors' should be returned.. I tried to put it contributors.contributors, but that made no difference

Comment: @ Ronak Patel, that's just to define the number of rows in albums, so I can loop through them .. something stupid or not obvious going on here?

Comment: So the table `contributors` has a column `contributors` (sorry for saying row above)?

Comment: hi kingkero, bit ugly maybe, but yes that's the case indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php

> **FIELD**
>
> The name or offset of the field being retrieved.
>
> It can be the field's offset, the field's name, or the field's table dot field 
>   name (tablename.fieldname). If the column name has
>   been aliased ('select foo as bar from...'), use the alias instead of
>   the column name. If undefined, the first field is retrieved.

You're just using the table name contributors, so either you need to specify a single field or limit your select to only the fields you want

```
$contributors[] = mysql_result($result, $i, 'contributors.name');
```

OR

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT contributors.* 
    FROM albums 
    LEFT JOIN contributors ON albums.album_id = contributors.album_id 
    ORDER BY albums.datum DESC; 
") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: hmm, contributors is actualli also a column in the table contributors, apparently not so nice naming, but that way I am in fact selecting a name, and not a table ..

Comment: you should be able to do contributors.contributors `$contributors[] = mysql_result($result, $i, 'contributors.contributors');`